# CMake generator expression is not evaluated

Tags: cmake

I cannot understand what I'm doing wrong.
I'm always getting the string `"$<TARGET_FILE:tgt1>"` instead of the path to the library.

I've created the dummy project.

Here is my root CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.0) # also tried 2.8 with the same result
set(PROJECT_NAME CMP0026)

add_subdirectory(src)

set(TGT_PATH $<TARGET_FILE:tgt1>)
message(STATUS "${TGT_PATH}")
```

Here is my src/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(tgt1 a.c)
```

File `a.c` is created and is empty

I've tried the following generators: Visual Studio 2013 Win64, Ninja and MingW Makefile. I've used Android toolchain for the last two, downloaded from [here](https://github.com/taka-no-me/android-cmake)

I expect that the last `message(STATUS` command would print full path to the library. However, all variants print the string `$<TARGET_FILE:tgt1>`.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Generator expressions are not evaluated at configure time (when CMake is parsing CMakeLists, executing commands like `add_target()` or `message()` etc.). At this time, a generator expression is just a literal string - the character `$` followed by `<`, then `T`, then ...

Evaluation of generator expressions happens at *generate* time (that's why they are called "generator expressions"). Generate time occurs after all CMake code is parsed and processed, and CMake is starting to act on the data therein to produce buildsystem files. Only *then* does it have all the information necessary to evaluate generator expressions.

So you can only really use generator expressions for things which occur at generate time or later (such as build time). A contrived example would be this:

```
add_custom_target(
  GenexDemo
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "$<TARGET_FILE:tgt1>"
  VERBATIM
)
```

At configure time, CMake will record the literal string `$<TARGET_FILE:tgt1>` as the argument of `COMMAND`. Then at generate time (when the location of `tgt1` is known for each configuration and guaranteed not to change any more), it will substitute it for the generator expression.

Comment: Thanks. Now I see. Therefore the best variant in my case would be switching to the old CMP0026 behavior.

Comment: @wl2776 The question is, do you really need the location at configure time?

Comment: @Agnew. Looks like yes I do. I call configure_file in one of my CMakeLists, and therefore need that path during config time.

Comment: @wl2776 Can't you use `file(GENERATE)` instead? That can expand generator expressions.

Comment: @Agnew. Will try. What should I use instead of `@ONLY`?

Comment: @wl2776 I'm not saying `file(GENERATE)` is a drop-in replacement; it's not. What you *could* do is run the file through `configure_file` normally, then `file(READ)` the configured output, and use that as input for `file(GENERATE)`. Or replace the mid-file configuration step with `string(CONFIGURE)`.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thank you for your help! However, I think `configure_file` would be more readable in my case.

Comment: There is this thread on the cmake-mailing list, which discusses this problem: http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/cmake/2015-April/060350.html